# Cast PgArray or java.sql.Array to a Scala collection

Tags: java, scala, casting, psql

I have a postgres query that uses the `array_agg()` function to return a PgArray of values. Running this query with a simple `java.sql.PreparedStatement` I get back a `java.sql.ResultSet`.

After `val arrayCol = resultSet.getArray("array_agg_column_name")` I have a `java.sql.Array`

printing arrayCol looks like

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Calling `arrayCol.getArray` gives me an `Object`

I'm unsure of how to work with either of the Object or java.sql.Array types in my Scala code. Doing a simple `asInstanceOf[List[Int]]` fails with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List
```

While casing with `asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]` leads to

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to [I
```

If I `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

And then try using `asScala` I get

```
value asScala is not a member of Object
```

or " ... of java.sql.Array", depending if I call `getArray`.

What is the correct way to get parse a field resulting from a psql `array_agg` function?

Comment: Can you try `resultSet.getArray("array_agg_column_name").getArray.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]].toList` ?

Comment: Ah, right. Trying that gives: `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to [I`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `json_agg` in lieu of `array_agg` in the postgres query, and then do:

```
resultSet.getString("array_agg_column_name")
```

From here, you can do as you like. We use Circe to decode Json to Scala objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can still cast it to `Array[AnyRef]` and convert it to another type by iterating through the array.

```
val arrayCol = resultSet.getArray("array_agg_column_name")
.getArray().asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]

val ans = arrayCol.map(i => i.asInstanceOf[Int])
```